# Build CSS-like Android spinner animation ( Stacked ProgressBar elements )

Tags: android, html, css, progress-bar, android-animation

So I've been looking into creating a "fancier" loading spinner for Android and the design that I am thinking of is the folowing:

[image]

[image]

Here is a live version of such a spinner using CSS:
  http://codepen.io/xixao/pen/jvxFc `link`

**Idea**
My idea is to somehow put two spinners on top of each other - make one spin the opposite direction.

**Question:**
I am wondering if there will be any pitfalls in using this kind of design? Has anyone tried layering more than 1 ProgressBar elements to work in a synchronous state.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you will find appropriate solution in [this](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/76) collection of different ProgressIndicators.